# R: Split a xts columns into variables

Tags: r, split, xts

I have a xts with a structure like this(if seen in a dataframe-like structure):

```
Date     Observation1 Observation2 Observation3 ....
1/1/2000      5             7           9
1/2/2000      3             1           8
....
```

What I need is the quickest way how to get now individual xts variables called Observation1, Observation2 and Observation3 with their respective data...How can I split the original xts up like this using the column names?

Answer (score 3):

I would just put them in a list, using `as.list`:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
y <- as.list(x)
str(y)
```